# random.choice not acting random at all

Tags: python, django, random

I have been working on a silly magic item creator that makes use of diffrent lists with stuff that can happen, feelings, coluers and so on. i have been using random.choice to pick from these lists but somehow the items generated do not really seem random at all.

when i run it 10 times in a row i get stuff like:

> A feather that causes horrible visions of an impending disaster, when
>   starring at it
>
> A lamp that makes you feel drunk when you lick a person who has
>   something you want
>
> A feather that makes you feel drunk when you lick a person who has
>   something you want
>
> A dagger that makes you feel drunk when you lick a person who has
>   something you want
>
> A feather that causes horrible visions of an impending disaster, when
>   starring at it
>
> A lamp that glows white when you touch a person thinking of you
>
> A book that makes you feel drunk when you lick a person who has
>   something you want
>
> A cane that makes you feel drunk when you lick a person who has
>   something you want
>
> A marble that makes you feel drunk when you lick a person who has
>   something you want
>
> A needle that makes you feel drunk when you lick a person who has
>   something you want

the first variable, item seems random enough, but from then on it starts repeating it self, the you feel drunk, is one possibility of a list of 10+ possibilities and the lick is from a list of 5.

```
makesyous = ["sad", "happy", "cold", "warm", "itchy", "laugh", "cough", "sing", "tired", "dizzy", "feel drunk", "uncomfortable", "feel like the opposite gender"]
sences = ["you see", "you smell", "you hear", "you touch", "you lick"]
```

they are all of them called thorugh a sceries of linked functions (thats is not the order the lilts and functions are wridden in the code, this is just to illustrate how i do stuff)

```
def generate():
    string = "A " + item() + " that " + action()
    return string

def item():
    x = random.choice(items)
    return(x)

def action():
    x = random.choice(actions)
    return(x)

actions = [short(), makesyou() + " "+ when(), random.choice(dostuff)]

def makesyou():
    x = "makes you " + random.choice(makesyous)
    return(x)

def when():
    x = random.choice(whens) + " " + sence()
    return(x)
```

am i doing somthing wrong (i know my code is badly structured, sorry about that) or is the random.choice working as intented?

Comment: It looks like you're calling `random.choice` (and calling all your randomising functions) inside a list. You know that the list will only get evaluated once, right?

Comment: wow, that was fast
no, i did not think of that. that looks like that could possibly explain it.
i will try and see if i can find a way around that, thank you very much.
My python skills are more or less non existent at this point :)

Comment: @JustHereForFun: Condense your problem into a single script that is self-contained and runs. Your code currently doesn't produce the output you have above and it isn't clear how you're doing that.

Comment: @khelwood, your observation was correct and thanks to you i have found a solution to the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

khelwoods observation seems to be correct, and the proplem has been solved by putting everything else inside the generate() function, probably not the best solution but it seems to work.

i now get outputs like

> A coin that glows green when you smell a person who has the same god
>   as you
>
> A coin purse that glows gold every time you touch an enemy
>
> A marble that deal 1d2 damage when you see a person who has the same
>   god as you
>
> A lamp that glows red every time you hear a person thinking of you
>
> A cane that makes you sad when you lick a person of higher status than
>   you
>
> A lamp that becomes immovable when the command word is spoken, you
>   know the command word
>
> A lamp that summons a glowing orb for 1d2 rounds every time you lick a
>   person who has something you want
>
> A locket that when shaken produces a brilliant red dust, this dust is
>   flammable
>
> A needle that makes you able to speak with animals, but they only
>   speak a language you do not understand
>
> A ring that makes whoever touches it feel cold

So once agine, thank you khelwood, savior of weekend projects!